# Ubuntu Studio 20.04 FireWire compatibility

Tags: sound, alsa, music, firewire

I have been using Ubuntu Studio for 5 months, before 19.04 then 19.10, on a PC  with FireWire sound cards that currently work well.

In the presentation notes of the new version of Ubuntu Studio 20.04 I saw FireWire hardware will no longer be supported due to kernel compatibility problems.

In Ubuntu Studio 19.10 control, I activated the ALSA backend jack, and the FireWire audio interface (Tascam edirol 66) works well, but when I activate the Firewire backend jack the interface disappears.  I think the firewire stack currently used is ALSA's.

Question: Will the ALSA FireWire stack continue to work on the Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS version if the FireWire backend jack in the new Ubuntu Studio control is removed?

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For 20.04 questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 20.04 is 23rd April 2020 when your question will be on-topic here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the ALSA backend, the ALSA firewire backend will continue to work so long as ALSA sees the device. The Firewire backend in Ubuntu Studio Controls was intended for devices that required FFADO, which proved to be problematic.

For that reason, since Firewire devices are ancient and no longer manufactured, unless they simply work with the ALSA backend, they will not be supported by Ubuntu Studio going forward.

Comment: FOR THE RECORD: Erich Eickmeyer is the flavor lead of the Ubuntu Studio flavor of Ubuntu.  This is coming straight from an authoritative source.

Comment: Thanks !, this reassures me, I have seen that the firewire-alsa stack modules include snd-firewire-tascam (A driver for FireWire series produced by TEAC Corp. as a brand of TASCAM. Since Linux 4.4), so I hope it will continue to to work, as my workstation is based on firewire -ediroll 66 and I would not be forced to change the operating system again (I come from Kxstudio) and, for now with Ubuntustudio I get on pretty well !.